Not showing up activmq admin page
I have installed apache-activemq-5.18.5 on Amazon Linux on EC2 instance.
When I run command systemctl start activemq.service, I get below output-

But when I hit url to open activemq broker page, I get below screen-

These are the Security Groups Inbound Rules set-

These are the logs in activemq.log file-

I dont know what wrong I am doing.
I changed the value of host attribute in jetty.xml to 0.0.0.0 as shown below-

Can someone help me please?

This question is similar to: ActiveMQ console not available. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi @AnonCoward, I changed the value of host attribute to 0.0.0.0 as you suggested (edited above question), but didn't worked.

@AnonCoward, Also please note that in the question you mentioned, its saying  "Unable to connect", but in my case its  showing "refused to connect". I also have installed tomcat server on the same EC2 instance which works fine when accessing tomcat admin page

solution added in aswers

It finally worked...after changing value of "host" appribute of "jettyPort" element in jetty.xml, we need to restart the EC2 instance.
